# Help on understanding CNF(Conjunctive Normal Form) conversion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra, conjunctive-normal-form

Currently i have 3 situations as such:

```
B: You choose bibimbap
H: You choose haggis
M: You choose manakish
```

I'm required to write a proposition in Conjunctive Normal Form using B,H,M that is True when 'you choose either bibimbap or both of the other items'.

The proposition i came up with is:

(B Λ ¬H Λ ¬M) v (¬B Λ H Λ M)

and the help i need is the conversion process to CNF. I used Wolfram Alpha to produce a CNF as follows:

(¬B V ¬M) Λ (B Λ H) Λ (¬H V M)

but i want to convert the proposition on my own but I really don't fully understand how the conversion works. I'll appreciate if i get a detailed guide on converting to CNF as I'm very confused about the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know the FOIL principle from high school algebra, right?

$$(a + b)(c + d) = ac+ad+bc+bd$$

Well, with larger terms it still works the same way: pick all different combinations. E.g:

$$(a + b + c)(d + e + f) = ad+ae+af+bd+be+bf+cd+ce+cf$$

Now, as it turns out, in boolean algebra the same distributive principles hold. So, applied to your statement, we get:

$$(B \land \neg H \land \neg M) \lor (\neg B \land H \land M) = \text{ (Distribution)}$$

$$ (B \lor \neg B) \land (B \lor H) \land (B \lor M) \land (\neg H \lor \neg B) \land (\neg H \lor H) \land (\neg H \lor M ) \land (\neg M \lor \neg B) \land (\neg M \lor H) \land (\neg M \lor M ) $$

Now, we can get rid of tautologies like $B \lor \neg B$:

$$ (B \lor \neg B) \land (B \lor H) \land (B \lor M) \land (\neg H \lor \neg B) \land (\neg H \lor H) \land (\neg H \lor M ) \land (\neg M \lor \neg B) \land (\neg M \lor H) \land (\neg M \lor M )= \text{ (Complement)}$$

$$ \top \land (B \lor H) \land (B \lor M) \land (\neg H \lor \neg B) \land \top \land (\neg H \lor M ) \land (\neg M \lor \neg B) \land (\neg M \lor H) \land \top = = \text{ (Identity)}$$

$$ (B \lor H) \land (B \lor M) \land (\neg H \lor \neg B) \land (\neg H \lor M ) \land (\neg M \lor \neg B) \land (\neg M \lor H)$$

OK, now you can apply something called [the Consensus Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consensus_theorem):

$(P \land Q) \lor (\neg Q \land R) \lor (P \land R) =  (P \land Q) \lor (\neg Q \land R)$

And its dual principle is:

$(P \lor Q) \land (\neg Q \lor R) \land (P \lor R) =  (P \lor Q) \land (\neg Q \lor R)$

Applied to your statement, we can see that $B \lor M$ is the consensus of $B \lor H$ and $\neg H \lor M$, and hence can be removed. Likewise, $\neg H \lor \neg B$ is the consensus of $\neg H \lor M $ and $\neg M \lor \neg B$, and $\neg M \lor H$ is the consensus of $\neg M \lor \neg B$ and $B \lor H$, so those can be removed as well, leaving us with:

$$ (B \lor H) \land (B \lor M) \land (\neg H \lor \neg B) \land (\neg H \lor M ) \land (\neg M \lor \neg B) \land (\neg M \lor H) = \text{ (Consensus x3)}$$

$$ (B \lor H) \land (\neg H \lor M ) \land (\neg M \lor \neg B) $$

Comment: Much thanks! I didn't know about this. Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. Appreciated it a lot.

Comment: @Maxxx Glad I could help!